# Quick Sort in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have tried to implement the traditional approach of Quicksort of "C" in PHP. The way it is supposed to work it is not working in PHP. This logic works in C but not in PHP.

- First processed the partition part
- swap the pivot values with the $upper
- use of quicksort function recursively

```
<?php
$array=array(7, 6, 5, 9, 2, 1, 15, 7);
$L=0;
$U=count($array)-1;
function Partition($a, $lower, $Upper)
{   
        $i=$lower;
        $j=$Upper;
        $pivot=$a[lower];

        while($i<$j)
        {

        while($a[$i]<$pivot)
        {
            $i++;
        }

        while($a[$j]>$pivot)
        {
            $j--;
        }

        if($i<$j)
        {
            $temp = $a[$i];
            $a[$i] = $a[$j];
            $a[$j] = $temp;
        }
        $i++;
        }
        $a[$lower]=$a[$j];
        $a[$j]=$pivot;

        return $j;
}
function QuickSort($a, $lower, $Upper)
{
    if($lower<$Upper)
    {
        $loc= Partition($a, $lower, $Upper);
        QuickSort($a, $lower, $loc-1);
        QuickSort($a, $loc+1, $Upper);
    }
    print_r($a);
}
QuickSort($array, $L, $U);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: One problem is that you need to pass your arrays by reference, not by value: `function Partition(&$a, $lower, $Upper)` and `function QuickSort(&$a, $lower, $Upper)`. Without the `&`, the *value* of the array will be passed and the original won't be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are not passed by reference by default in PHP.  (They're not simply pointers like they would be in C.) So your functions aren't actually changing the input array.

I've modified your function declarations below and it now works as expected.

Also, you need `$pivot=$a[lower]` to be `$pivot=$a[$lower];`;

```
<?php
$array=array(7, 6, 5, 9, 2, 1, 15, 7);
$L=0;
$U=count($array)-1;
function Partition(&$a, $lower, $Upper)
{   
        $i=$lower;
        $j=$Upper;
        $pivot=$a[$lower];

        while($i<$j)
        {

        while($a[$i]<$pivot)
        {
            $i++;
        }

        while($a[$j]>$pivot)
        {
            $j--;
        }

        if($i<$j)
        {
            $temp = $a[$i];
            $a[$i] = $a[$j];
            $a[$j] = $temp;
        }
        $i++;
        }
        $a[$lower]=$a[$j];
        $a[$j]=$pivot;

        return $j;
}
function QuickSort(&$a, $lower, $Upper)
{
    if($lower<$Upper)
    {
        $loc= Partition($a, $lower, $Upper);
        QuickSort($a, $lower, $loc-1);
        QuickSort($a, $loc+1, $Upper);
    }
    print_r($a);
}
QuickSort($array, $L, $U);
print_r($array);
```

It's worth noting that the sort functions for arrays that PHP provides already use an implementation of QuickSort.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. it is quite helpful

Comment: Sure, no problem! 

If this does solve the issue you were having, there's a little checkbox to mark this as the accepted answer. It'll let people browsing the question list know that you've found an answer and give me them sweet sweet reputation points. :D

Comment: Can you use Quick Sort to sort letters?  Or is it created just for Numbers?

Comment: @13garth The above implementation is specifically for numbers, but so long as you have a way to do the comparison you can sort anything. It's worth noting that PHP's `sort` functions (like `usort`, `asort`, `uasort`) use Quick Sort, so implementing your own quicksort in PHP is only really useful as a learning exercise.

Comment: Thank you @EPB I was doing a technical assessment